# Is it true that all smooth group schemes can be deformed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, deformation-theory

Consider for instance the map $\mathbb Z/p^2 \to \mathbb Z/p$ and suppose we are given a group smooth scheme $G$ over $\mathbb Z/p$. Is it always possible to lift it to a smooth group scheme $G'$ over $\mathbb Z/p^2$?

I know this is true if $G$ is an Abelian variety and also if it is an affine group scheme. Can the general case be reduced to this using for instance, Chevalley's theorem?

For any smooth group scheme $G$, we know that there is an exact sequence:
$$0 \to H \to G \to A$$
with $H$ an affine group scheme and $A$ an Abelian variety and we can lift $H$ and $A$ but does this necessarily give us a lift of $G$?

(I am interested in the general case of deformation over small extensions of Artin rings, not just the example of $\mathbb Z/p^2 \to \mathbb Z/p$).

Comment: Abelian varieties can always be lifted to characteristic zero, but not always over the Witt vectors. This suggests that the answer to the general question is negative. (There is a deformation theory of (smooth) group schemes in SGA3, Chapter III that you might find useful. A more general theory can be found in Illusie's Complexe Contangent ... v. 2.)

Comment: @ulrich But you can always lift Abelian varieties over the quotients of the Witt vectors, I believe. I think what goes wrong is going from the inverse limit of these lifts (=formal scheme) to an actual honest scheme over W(k). I believe Illusie explains this in his section on formal schemes in FGA explained. Thanks for the references

Comment: Ah, by the general case of deformation i meant for all small extensions but not in the broader sense that you seem to have understood it as. Let me clarify that!

Comment: I agree with what you say about abelian varieties, the difficulty is only with lifting polarisations.